# ¿Por qué JavaScript me cambia un tipo string a un booleano?

Tags: javascript, parsear

Tengo una función que retorna un arreglo de objetos, el punto es que cada objeto tiene dos atributos de tipo *string* (`objectN` y `recordType`), los *string* que usan estos campos son subcadenas que se obtienen de un `split(".")`, el problema es que `objectN` se convierte en un booleano cuando en realidad le paso una subcadena proveniente del `split(".")`. Desafortunadamente el parseo no soluciona este problema.

Código:

```
function getFormatArray(array){
        let aFormatedArray = [];            
        let indexObject = 0;
        let indexRecordType = 1;

        for(let obj of array){                
            let aStrings = obj.recordType.split(".");                
            let ok = aStrings[0]; 
            let anotherOk = aStrings[1];                              
            console.log("ok: " + ok);
            console.log("anotherOk: " + anotherOk );
            let formatedObject = {
                objectN : String(aStrings[indexObject]),
                recordType : aStrings[indexRecordType],
                visible : obj.visible,
                default_x : obj.default_x
            };                
            aFormatedArray.push(formatedObject);
        }
        console.log(aFormatedArray);
        return aFormatedArray;
    }
```

La salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un ejemplo del array que paso:

`{visible_type_info: Array(6), visible: true, recordType_type_info: Array(6), recordType: "Account.testRecord", personAccountDefault_type_info: Array(6), …}`

Comment: El código parece que está correcto, hacé esto  `arr.forEach((o)=>{
console.log(o.recordType)
})` porque casi seguro hay un problema con esa propiedad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, encontré el error y no estaba en esa función, supongo que se debe a algo llamado shallow copy  de js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript tiene unas conversiones implícitas, puedes documentarte acá http://2ality.com/2013/04/quirk-implicit-conversion.html

Prueba con la función .toString() en esta parte "objectN : aStrings[indexObject].toString()"

```
function getFormatArray(array){
        let aFormatedArray = [];            
        let indexObject = 0;
        let indexRecordType = 1;

        for(let obj of array){                
            let aStrings = obj.recordType.split(".");                
            let ok = aStrings[0]; 
            let anotherOk = aStrings[1];                              
            console.log("ok: " + ok);
            console.log("anotherOk: " + anotherOk );
            let formatedObject = {
                objectN : aStrings[indexObject].toString(),
                recordType : aStrings[indexRecordType],
                visible : obj.visible,
                default_x : obj.default_x
            };                
            aFormatedArray.push(formatedObject);
        }
        console.log(aFormatedArray);
        return aFormatedArray;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, encontré el error y no estaba en esa función, supongo que se debe a algo llamado shallow copy  de js